# openlayers-3 Firefox 37.0.1 versus 37.0.2 mapserver rendering bug?

Tags: firefox, openlayers-3

I think upgrading from Firefox 37.0.1 to 37.0.2 in Win7 64 has revealed a bug either in my code or the OL3 code. Two of my layers are no longer displayed in the correct position. The two layers that are incorrect are both using a URL that indicates ArcGIS REST services and ends with mapserver. No other layers are using sources similar to these 2 that are the problems:

```
http://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nidis/usdroughtoutlook/MapServer
http://apps.fs.fed.us/arcx/rest/services/EDW/EDW_Watersheds_01/MapServer
```

**Details**:

I am displaying multiple layers from multiple sources in a OpenLayers3 map. Everything was displaying properly using Firefox 37.0.1 running in Windows 7, 64 bit. Without any change to the javascript code, two of the layers no longer display properly. They are offset to the south and east relative to where they used to display correctly.  For example, the southern tip of Florida in those two layers now is on top of Cuba. The only difference that I know was made is that Firefox was updated to 37.0.2.

**Testing results**
I tested with prior versions of my code that I am certain were correct in 37.0.1, but those now display incorrectly on 37.0.2.

I tested on another Windows 7, 64 machine with 37.0.1 and the current code displays the correct results.

I tested on both Windows 7 machines using Chrome and layers displayed correctly.

I tested using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17691 with product update version 11.0.17 and the layers do not display correctly.

I conclude that the Firefox update is responsible for the display errors. However, I cannot tell if this is a problem with Firefox or the OL3 code.

Code excerpts:
I have included the code that creates the layers that are not working. I have skipped most of the code since it works for the other layers and for Chrome.  I have added some additional parameters (layerCaption, layerCode, showMenu) to facilitate other processing. Each layer is pushed onto an array (myLayers) that is used to define the map. 
The OL library is referenced as:

```
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript
```

javascript

```
var huc = new ol.layer.Tile({
title: 'Watersheds',
layerCaption: 'Watersheds',
layerCode: 'huc',
showMenu: true,
source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
    url: 'http://apps.fs.fed.us/arcx/rest/services/EDW/EDW_Watersheds_01/MapServer',
    params: {
        'layers': 0,    // 0 is HUC-2... 5 is HUC-12
        'bbox': '-126.0 24.5 -65.0 51.0',
        'transparent': 'false',
        'f': 'image'
    },
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
        html: 'Hydrologic Unit Boundaries, US Forest Service Enterprise Map Services Program'
    })]
}),
visible: false,
opacity: 0.70
});
```

The second layer is:

```
var ncdcDrought = new ol.layer.Tile({
title: 'NOAA National Climatic Data Cecnter Drought Forecast',
layerCaption: 'Drought Forecast',
layerCode: 'ncdcDrought',
showMenu: true,
source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
    url: 'http://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nidis/usdroughtoutlook/MapServer',
    params: {
        'LAYERS': '0',
        'bbox': '-126.0 24.5 -65.0 51.0',
        'bboxSR': '4326',
        'imageSR': '4019',
        'transparent': 'false',
        'f': 'image'
    }
}),
visible: false,
opacity: 0.70
});
myLayers.push(ncdcDrought);
```

Code for map creation:

```
var view = new ol.View({
 //center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
projection: 'EPSG:4326',
center: [-90, 40],
zoom: 4
});
var map = new ol.Map({
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.ScaleLine({
        units: 'us'
    })
]),
target: 'map',
layers: myLayers,
view: view
});
```

I have tried to provide the relevant details. I can supply more information if this is not sufficient.

Thank you.

Jeff